# Removing 0 before decimal in {gtsummary}

Tags: r, gtsummary

In the field of psychology, it is customary to remove a 0 before the decimal when the value above 1.0 is impossible.

Therefore, I'd like to change p values from, for example:

> p = 0.01 to p = .01

Additionally, when making a regression table using `tbl_regression`,
I'd like to change standardized beta coefficients to, for example:

> beta = -0.43 to beta = -.43 (in the regression table)

Or, R^2:

> R^2 = 0.234 to R^2 = .234 (through `add_glance_statistics`)

Is there a way to do this? I have looked at style tools, but there does not seem to be a configuration for this.

Comment: The gtsummary package has a Journal Themes feature. For example, you can run `theme_gtsummary_journal("jama")` at the top of your script and all the results will be printed in the style of JAMA. We don't have a psychology journal yet, but are we welcome contributions. You can submit an Issue on the GitHub page to get started.  Typically, we'll model the theme after a top journal in the field. You provide us with links to relevant information (e.g. reporting guidelines, manuscript examples), and we can create a theme to round numbers for that journal, for mat p-values, etc.

Comment: Check this page for examples https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/theme_gtsummary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `modify_fmt_fun` to modify the format of the table. Here, I use `trial` data from `gtsummary` to show how you can remove leading 0s for `p.value`. After applying `sub` to remove the leading 0, it returns NA for the other rows. So, I use `gsub` to change the NA back to blanks for the table.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

trial[c("age", "grade", "trt")] %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(update = p.value ~ function(val) {
    as.character(sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", val))) %>%
      gsub("NA", "", .)
  })
```

Output

[image]

If you need to do the same on others, then you can add in additional parameters. Here, I add in beta (i.e., estimate) to `modify_fmt_fun`.

```
lm(age ~ marker + grade, trial) %>%
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_source_note(
    label = list(df  ~ "Degrees of Freedom", sigma ~ "\U03C3"),
    fmt_fun = df ~ style_number,
    include = c(r.squared, AIC, sigma, df)
  ) %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(update = c(estimate, p.value) ~ function(val) {
    as.character(sub("^(-?)0.", "\\1.", sprintf("%.2f", val))) %>%
      gsub("NA", "", .)
  })
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. In relation to p-value, how to retain carats in p-value? For example, format p=.028 to p=.28, but leave p<.001 as it is.